# Why can't I get this input element to act on my html?

Tags: html, css, input, label

**My goal: create Night Mode button that will change colors of website to darker colors.**

Method: I used a label element that was tied to an input element which when activated would change the color of anything inside of the website. (think a "night mode" button that will darken the entire site for night time readers).

Can someone tell me why the code I came up with is not working? I already cross checked with other coders and we don't understand why... it might be something very simple.

```css
* {
  color:red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  width:80%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  border: 1px solid rgb(22, 36, 218);
}
.header{
  height:60px;
}
.nav {
  height:30px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}
input#Color {
  position:absolute;
}
input#Color:checked + .nav {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- DOCKMANN INDEX PAGE - CODE: D001 -->
<html>

<head>
<!-- CSS --><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
<!-- JS --><script src="script.js"></script>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <!-- END HEAD -->
<body>
  <label for="Color">Poop</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Color"/>
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      test header
    </div>
    <!-- end header -->
    <div class="nav">
      <p>
        test nav
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- end nav -->
    <div class="content">
      test content
      <div class="mainContent">
        mainContent
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        Sidebar
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end content -->
    <div class="footer">
      test footer
    </div>
    <!-- end footer -->
 </div>
 <!-- end wrapper -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `.nav` is nested in `.wrapper` and the CSS expects it to be a sibling.

Try

`input#Color:checked + .wrapper`

or if you only want the nav affected;

`input#Color:checked + .wrapper .nav`

Comment: [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/zmzndt9a/) a fiddle demonstration. Beat me by a bit :)

Comment: Thank you Rose, for helping out a noob! You fixed it.

Comment: Sorry @AndrewLi :)  You went to all that effort to make a fiddle, too!